# BC30002 Type 'abcdefg' is not defined Error when building VS 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a project that is coming up with 5 BC30002 errors, type 'typename' is not defined. However, when I double-click the error to open the offending line of code, intellisence does not show the line as an error, and in fact, when I clear out the name and re-type, intellisence finds the type for me.

One thing I have noticed is that the referenced library in question appears correctly if I remove it and add it back in. It shows the version number of the DLL and "Copy Local" is showing as "True". After I build the project, I then see the version number as 0.0.0.0 and local path is set to "False" (see below). I think this is the root of the problem as it seems that during the build process, it loses track of this DLL.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

[image: Screen Shot - Visual Studio Project References]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your VS folder?

Comment: Which folder specifically?

Comment: @RobertHill In the root of your project folder, if you are using Visual Studio, there is a hidden folder named .vs. Visual Studio caches files there to help it run faster; however, the files get corrupted sometimes and Visual Studio acts strangely. 

Another suggestion would be to search your project for abcdefg and see where it is being used.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that did the trick. Geez, hours spent on this and it was as simple as deleting the .VS hidden folder!!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late of a reply but I just had the same issue and resolved it by updating the NuGet packages for the `typename`. For some I had to then downgrade the packages to their original version (some things were no longer working/present in the newer versions) but in the end the solution build and compiled just fine.